# Show 5 divs every row with all rows starting and ending same place

Tags: html, css

I am looking to create 5 divs (tiles) on every row.

I partly achieved this by checking for every 5th element and inserting an empty div if the count is a multiple of 5. However, this results in the each row starting and ending at different positions depending on the length of the word. Instead, I am looking to have all the start and end positions be aligned, pretty much like a table.

Here is a code sandbox I have created to demo this

https://codesandbox.io/s/grids-5-on-a-line-wghvs?file=/src/App.tsx

Here is a picture of my current output
[image]

Is it possible to achieve this using CSS styling, or would I need to create a table instead? Could someone please suggest a solution?

Comment: Use CSS grid for this.

Comment: set the width to 20%, or as @cloned has said, use display grid, which is actually the preferred method

Comment: here is a grid example as told : https://codesandbox.io/s/grids-5-on-a-line-9ru5q?file=/src/App.tsx but with 1fr instead 20% ;)

Answer (score 3):

You can use a CSS grid to achieve this.

```
<div class="grid">
  <div class="inner-card"></div>
  <div class="inner-card"></div>
  ...
</div>
```

```
.grid {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 20% 20% 20% 20% 20%;
}
```

This will create a grid, with each column occupying 20% in width. If you need spacing between the elements, you can use the `row-gap` and `column-gap` properties.
You can read more about CSS grids and how they work here: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/

Comment: Thanks Guillermo. That works for me. Only issue however is that, the text at the center of div gets position to one side, even with text-align:center. Shall read through css grid a bit more. Shall accept answer upon time limit.

Comment: That's odd, if it's a big issue you could post a screenshot and code for us to see. And I'm glad my answer helped